# Bencevans Screenshot-Desktop function using NodeJs in Laravel

Tags: node.js, laravel

I have succeeded to run the Bencevans Screenshot-Desktop function using NodeJs, but at the moment I have trouble implementing it in Laravel. this is my code:

```
const screenshot = require('screenshoot-desktop')
const fs = require('fs')

screenshot().then((img) => {
fs.writeFile('out.jpg', img, function (err) {
   if (err) {
      throw err
   }
   console.log('written to out.jpg')
})
}).catch((err) => {
      throw err
})
```

and in Laravel I tried this way on blade code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Capture</title>
</head>
<body>
<button>Test</button>
<script>
    const screenshot = require('screenshoot-desktop')
    const fs = require('fs')

    screenshot().then((img) => {
    fs.writeFile('out.jpg', img, function (err) {
        if (err) {
        throw err
        }
        console.log('written to out.jpg')
    })
    }).catch((err) => {
    throw err
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ya of course that is wrong, but I confuse to implement in Laravel, anybody could help? appreciate it

Comment: Client side and server side programming are two completely different things. You can't just copy code from one to the other.

Comment: @miken32 so I can't implement that code benchevans node js to laravel?

Comment: how about laravel mix @miken32?

Answer (score 0):

The [screenshot-desktop](https://github.com/bencevans/screenshot-desktop) module utilises Node.js APIs and makes calls to other system utilities, such as the `screenshot` command line application on macOS. Thus this will not run in regular browsers. Electron can if Node.js APIs are enabled.

Instead, anyone looking for a browser option may be interested in the native [ScreenCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture) Web API available in most modern browsers.